# Error when I try to listen to cloud firestore collections from Android app

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying POC with Cloud Firestore in Android app. I have followed Firebase documentation and added following method :

```
private void initializeFirestoreAndListenToUserUpdates() {
    final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
            .setPersistenceEnabled(true)
            .build();
    db.setFirestoreSettings(settings);

    // Listen for users born before 1900.
    // You will get a first snapshot with the initial results and a new
    // snapshot each time there is a change in the results.
    db.collection("users")
            .whereLessThan("born", 1900)
            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot snapshots,
                                    @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                    if (e != null) {
                        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
                        return;
                    }

                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Current users born before 1900: " + snapshots.getDocuments());
                    List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = snapshots.getDocuments();
                    if (documents != null) {
                        for (DocumentSnapshot doc : documents) {
                            Log.d(LOG_TAG, doc.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

However at runtime I see following error in my logcat :

```
01-02 12:09:47.705 12977-13061/com.disha.quickride W/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: Status{code=FAILED_PRECONDITION, description=The Cloud Firestore API is not available for Cloud Datastore projects., cause=null}
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
```

From the Firebase console, I can confirm that Cloud Datastore is disabled and only Cloud Firestore is enabled in native mode. Also, I have a working internet connection on my android device. How can I rectify this error?

Comment: did you add "
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>" in manifest ?

Comment: @PavanVarma, Yes, this permission is already added

Comment: Please add the content of your both build.gradle files.

Comment: @AlexMamo I don't have those extra junk file in my project and not required to run my application.